# charAt issue whe running in Windows

Tags: java, char

I have this small piece of code that aims to replace accented letter with no accented letters.

```
protected String sinAcentos(String str) {

    // Cadena de caracteres original a sustituir.
    String original = "áàäéèëíìïóòöúùuñÁÀÄÉÈËÍÌÏÓÒÖÚÙÜÑçÇ";
    // Cadena de caracteres ASCII que reemplazarán los originales.
    String ascii = "aaaeeeiiiooouuunAAAEEEIIIOOOUUUNcC";

    String tmp = str;
    for (int i=0; i<original.length(); i++) {
        // Reemplazamos los caracteres especiales.
        tmp = tmp.replace(original.charAt(i), ascii.charAt(i));
    }//for i
    return tmp;
}
```

When I run this function from within IDE (eclipse) there is no error.
But then I export an create an executable product, that runs on Windows 7 and also Windows XP.

When the function runs an error occurs and the text is:

> Index out of bounds:34

So, 34 is the lenght of original string variable. therefore the loop shoul loop i between 0 and 33 , because the loop condition :  `i < original.lenght()` ...

I change the code adding a try...catch at the replace line, and that's how is working now.

Any idea what's wrong in the code?

Answer (score 3):

Please check the encoding of your Java source file and also check the charset used for both Strings.

There might be a mismatch between those and some encodings require more bytes than others for special characters (think UTF-8 vs. ISO-8859-1 for example).

Make sure that your Java source file is using UTF-8 and not ISO-8859-1 or a Windows-specific encoding like CP-1252.